# Typescript sub classes: refer to derived class in super class?

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
    parentList: List<A>;
}

class B extends A {}
```

Is there any way that `parentList` is automatically of type `List<B>` for class `B` (without redefining for every subclass)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types):

```
class A {
    public list: Array<this>;
}

class B extends A { }

declare const b: B;

const listOfB = b.list; // B[]

declare const a: A;

const listOfA = a.list; // A[]
```

Comment: I took a moment to find the (well hidden) new-docs for `this` type. Interesting. This is new to me (although I can't remember the last time I wrote a class in JS/TS)

Comment: Nice, did not use it either

Comment: @spender You can use poly this in interface definitions as well. `interface Int { ints: this[]; }`.